# jQuery error in .js file

Tags: jquery

I've just completed the JavaScript and jQuery basics, and I got two errors while executing the jquery in the .js file

1. `$` is uses before was defined
2. Missing 'used strict' statement

What should I do?

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: Please include a small code snipit that can be read quickly, and reproduces the problem. Also, see the Guide about asking good questions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Make sure jQuery is loaded before your custom js file or you can use `defer` attribute to `<script>` tag for jQuery and custom JS file.

for example:

```
<html>
  <head> ... </head>
  <body>

    ...

    <script src="jquery.js" />
    <script src="your_custom_js.js" />

  </body>
</html>
```